# Bluetooth custom Pairing using a windows service

Tags: service, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

We're working on an .net core 3.0 app  under UWP win 10. The app runs as a BLE central, connecting to BLE peripherals. We use the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth namespace which defines a Windows Runtime API that allows UWP desktop apps to interact with Bluetooth devices.

When we run the app as is, we can pair without issues. However when we wrap the model within a windows service, everything works but the pairing process which returns a Failed DevicePairingResultStatus for the pairAsync(pin_number) request. The code which is run remains exactly the same in both cases.
Pairing is performed with DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin, DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption) method.

We've tried running the service as logged on as Local System, Local Service, local user with admin privileges, Administrator and Network Service with the same results.

Windows 10 is updated as well as Bluetooth drivers, Bios etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the difference exists between running as a windows service and running as an app? And how to bypass this?

Thanks!

Comment: Lot of UWP classes/methods requires to run in UI thread.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the WPF APP would fail to pair as well?

Comment: No, WPF can pair without problem. Even classic service can execute pairing without problem.

Comment: We've tried running the pairing segment of the code from a UI thread. No luck. We get the same Failed DevicePairingResultStatus.

Comment: Are you use that device requires legacy PIN pairing? Are you sure that device's MITM protection requires encryption?

Comment: The provide pin portion, I'm sure we need. The encryption portion- we tried both with and without, and can not get it to work.

Comment: Any update? Would like to know the limitaion of BluetoothLE on Windows